# SQL Update from Excel Columns

Tags: sql, sql-update

I need to update a SQL table with our current job info from an Excel sheet each time data captured from the Mfg equipment, I can do this by creating a stored procedure that I can execute using a JScript that is run by the program capturing the data and writing it to the Db.

I'm now able to query the Excel sheet fine and view the data that I need, but the formatting is a bit of a gotcha, without running queries to separate the data row by row then one update I can't think of how to update it.

Query against sheet:

```
 SELECT Item, L05, L08, L09, SS1, SS2, SS3
 FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY F8) AS rownumber, F1 AS Item, F2 AS L05, F3 AS L08, 4 AS L09, F5 AS SS1, F6 AS SS2, F7 AS SS3
    FROM OpenDataSource( 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Data Source="C:\Job.xlsx";Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=NO";')..."'Job Details$'") AS T2
  Where rownumber >= 5 AND rownumber<=8
```

Returns:

```
Item L05       L08        L09       SS1       SS2       SS3
WO   806314    806334     806618    806314    805886    807031
TE   TE2-05712 TE2-04481  TE2-06364 TE2-06345 TE2-06362 TE2-04420
TF   TF2-10874 TF2-07754A TF2-14249 tf2-10874 TF2-12635 TF2-12468
Qty  39144     82800      127200    36348     121800    50660
```

Each equipment line is a column, and each data item is a row in the sheet, I need to reference the values and update to the table that looks like this:

```
LINE      WO      TE      TF      Qty
Line05    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Line08    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Line09    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
SS1       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
SS2       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
SS3       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Ideally since the sheet is fixed I could reference the Excel cells individually in the update statement, but I haven't seen a way to do that if it is possible.

Comment: Ah, so you need to create a cross-tab... if I recall correctly it is not straightforward to do in sql server.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll can't say I've ever tried it, but will be researching as soon as I get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bluefeet This worked to pull the correct order of things, but all of the values were NULL, I wound up thinking outside the question a little and rather than re-arranging everything in T-SQL I created and hid a new Excel sheet in the workbook with cells linked to the original sheet in the order I need them, and then queried that instead.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the following:

```
select *
from
(
  select item, value, line
  from
  (
    <yourquery>
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for line in (L05, L08, L09,
                SS1, SS2, SS3)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for item in ([WO], [TE], [TF], [QTY])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6c40/3)

Comment: Sorry haven't had a chance to give this a shot yet, no ISP at my new house yet, I'll give it a shot tomorrow morning at the office.